# jakarta.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am new to Springboot and Java. I am trying to send an email from my Gmail account via Spring Boot.  So far I was able to run the code after all configurations. But throws

```
jakarta.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype
```

When calling the send method of MailSender.

```
@Service
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String text) {
        try{
            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);
            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

application.properties

```
    spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
    spring.mail.port=587
    spring.mail.username=mygmailaccount
    spring.mail.password=password
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
    # Other properties
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

build.gradle

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
 testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
 //implementation group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.2'
 implementation group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'jakarta.mail', version: '1.6.7'
```

Tried everything. Still not able to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding till now says that this is a version compatibility issue between your Jakarta and SpringBoot. If I was in your place I would do below steps

- Remove the explicit dependency on Jakarta and let the Spring Boot handle it.
- Comment out your last line of build.gradle file and it will look like this

`//implementation group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'jakarta.mail', version: '1.6.7'`

Make sure to run gradle clean build command after this

Comment: If issue is still there, share your SpringBoot version also

Comment: Actually, there were 2 problems. First I used JavaMailSender. So commenting on this threw "No Bean found" When JavaMailSender is AutoWired. Now I have changed to MailSender and commented was per your advice. This worked.